# Double click to select words connected with break

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text 2 and when I double click on word connected with underline like:

```
this_is_it
```

it will auto select whole phrase, but when is words connected with break symbol like this:

```
this-is-it
```

it will select only one of words, how can I set Sublime Text to select whole phrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify `"word_separators"` in user's `Preferences.sublime-settings`, the default is:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

Since `-` is minus in most programming language, it is included as default separator. You better modify syntax specific files (e.g. `Plain text.sublime-settings`) to suit your need.

http://compscientist.com/post/28272180856/word-separators